# How can I integrate quickblox framework with objective c headers files, in my swift project?

Tags: swift, xcode, quickblox, cocoapods-1.0.1, objc-bridging-header

I am integrating **Quickblox Framework** for chat feature into my own app in **Xcode 8.2** using **Swift 3.0**.

But while importing header files of **Quickblox Framework** in bridging header file, its giving errors

Has anyone done this kind of integration of **Quickblox Framework** in **Swift 3.0** ?

Comment: did you try this example in swift 3: https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample-chat-swift

Comment: yes, I implemented quickBlox for chat functionality in my app, what error exactly you get ?

Comment: @ sapana Ranipa problem getting with header files, i am unable to access header files

Comment: @muescha yes tried this example , but its working in demo by while integrating in my project framework not accessible

Comment: then you describe what you havedone and you should add your code and show us all the errors (screenshot or copy as text)

Comment: try to startover with a new project and show if this works and then compare with your project settings